# Does the same error guarantee of Java's Math.exp also apply to StrictMath.exp?

Tags: java, numeric, exp

In Java, I need to compute `(int)Math.exp(x)` in a platform independent way. To achieve platform independency, I have to use StrictMath instead: `(int)StrictMath.exp(x)`. Unfortunately, my measurements have shown that `StrictMath.exp` is significantly slower than `Math.exp`.

Therefore, I had the idea to compute `y = Math.exp(x)` first. [The interface of `Math.exp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#exp(double)) states that

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results must be semi-monotonic.

So, if `(int)(Math.nextDown(y)) == (int)(Math.nextUp(y))`, I can use `(int)y` as result. Only in the very rare case that `(int)(StrictMath.nextDown(y)) != (int)(StrictMath.nextUp(y))` (the result is expected to be in the `int` range), I need to additionally evaluate `(int)StrictMath.exp(x)`.

This strategy would be correct if `StrictMath.exp` had the same error guarantees as `Math.exp`.
Unfortunately, a corresponding statement is missing in the [`StrictMath.exp` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StrictMath.html#exp(double)). [The javadoc of StrictMath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StrictMath.html) just says

> To help ensure portability of Java programs, the definitions of some of the numeric functions in this package require that they produce the same results as certain published algorithms. These algorithms are available from the well-known network library netlib as the package "Freely Distributable Math Library," fdlibm. These algorithms, which are written in the C programming language, are then to be understood as executed with all floating-point operations following the rules of Java floating-point arithmetic.
>
> The Java math library is defined with respect to fdlibm version 5.3. Where fdlibm provides more than one definition for a function (such as acos), use the "IEEE 754 core function" version (residing in a file whose name begins with the letter e). The methods which require fdlibm semantics are sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan, exp, log, log10, cbrt, atan2, pow, sinh, cosh, tanh, hypot, expm1, and log1p.

Furthermore, the interface of the [exp function in the fdlibm library](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c) says that

> Accuracy: according to an error analysis, the error is always less than 1 ulp (unit in the last place).

Does the combination of all this information really imply that `StrictMath.exp` has the same error guarantee as `Math.exp`? Only a 100% guarantee would allow me to do the optimization described above.

Comment: Which Java version did you use? Since Java 17 the strict behaviour is the standard behaviour, and `Math` and `StrictMath` do exactly the same since Java 17 (`Math` calls the equivalent function in `StrictMath`). Though `Math.exp` may be intrinsified, which can cloud that assessment

Comment: I think the interfaces and the javadocs have not changed in the past Java versions. It is also not a problem that Math.exp can be intrinsified, as its error is explicitly stated in the interface. I am also not sure if really all Java implementations delegate to StrictMath. However, if they do, the StrictMath implementation must of course provide the same error guarantee.

Comment: Again, since Java 17, there is only the strict behaviour. See [JEP 306: Restore Always-Strict Floating-Point Semantics](https://openjdk.org/jeps/306), as far as I'm aware that also means that `Math` and `StrictMath` should now always produce the exact same result.

Comment: I am currently using Java 11. I know about the strict behavior of Java 17 which makes the strictfp keyword obsolete. However, I have not yet found anything that states the equivalence of Math and StrictMath.

Comment: As Stephen C pointed out below, there is no reason to assume that `Math` and `StrictMath` will give the same result in Java 17.

Comment: Given the implementation of `Math.exp` by default calls `StrictMath.exp`, I think it is safe to assume that it fulfills the requirements, otherwise `Math.exp` calling it would break its own contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the combination of all this information really imply that `StrictMath.exp` has the same error guarantee as `Math.exp`?

On the face of it<sup>1</sup>, the error guarantee is the same; i.e. it is less than 1 ulp.  But that isn't the same as saying that the error is the same!

The point of using `StrictMath` was not to guarantee that the error was the absolute minimum possible.  Rather, the point was to guarantee *reproducible* results, independent of programming language, hardware implementation and so on.

And the flip-side is that the `Math` methods are (still<sup>2</sup>) not specified to produce bit-for-bit identical results to their `StrictMath` equivalents.  As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) in Java 17 states:

> *"Unlike some of the numeric methods of class `StrictMath`, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class `Math` are not defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. This relaxation permits better-performing implementations **where strict reproducibility is not required**."*

---

> However, I have not yet found anything that states the equivalence of `Math` and `StrictMath`.

I don't think they are guaranteed to be equivalent: not in any version of Java.  Indeed, that would *contradict* the above javadoc quote.

---

<sup>1 - This is based on the text that you quoted in your question.

2 - While all floating point arithmetic operations in Java 17 and later have `strictfp` semantics (see [JEP 306](https://openjdk.org/jeps/306)), this doesn't automatically extend to `Math`.</sup>

Comment: The question was if the error guarantee is the same (1ulp) and not if the error is the same. I know that the results may be different. In my opinion, the specification is not entirely clear whether the 1ulp error also applies to StrictMath.exp.

Comment: 1) I answered that in the first sentence of my answer.  In my opinion it is facially clear.  2) You said: *"However, I have not yet found anything that states the **equivalence** of Math and StrictMath."*.

Comment: If the fdlibm exp-function written in C guarantees an error of 1ulp, it is not obvious to me that the same algorithm implemented in Java "with all floating-point operations following the rules of Java floating-point arithmetic" also gives an error of 1ulp.

Comment: The javadoc for `Math.exp` **specifies** that it does.   You quoted that text in your question!   Like I said, it is facially clear: on the face of the respective specifications.

Comment: Unfortunately, the javadoc for `StrictMath.exp` does not.

Comment: But ... as your OTHER quoted text points out, the spec for fdlibm version 5.4 **does**.   All the information is in the text of your question.

Comment: Repeating my comment above, I am not sure if the same error guarantee also applies to a Java port of the fdlibm algorithm, as the "Java floating-point-arithmetic" is not necessarily equivalent to that of C. In my opinion, this is missing in the argumentation or at least not obvious.

Comment: Nah.  1)  The text you quoted say clearly that the purpose of `StrictMath` is to behave like `fdlibm` version 5.4.  If it differs in the slightest detail, it does not meet those requirements ... and you run into the kind of computational inconsistencies that `fdlibm` and `StrictMath` are designed to avoid.  2) Indeed in Java 8 and earlier, `StrictMath.exp()` is a `native` method call to the `fdlibm` implementation.  (Via a shim that deals with exceptions, etctera ... if I recollect correctly.)  Check the source code.